# Unity UI List Element not showing unless I change screen size

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a UI Scroll View in Unity showing a list of Toggles that I dynamically populate. My problem is that when I instanciate a new element in this list, it is in the inspector but it is not rendered on the screen ?

This happens also when i manually add a ListElement GameObject to the content element of the list.

What is very weird is that if I move the window so that the screen size changes, it is drawn...   Cf. the two screen shots.

On the first screen shot, I added a ListElement prefab, like you can see, it is not drawn but it is there and active.

Then I resized the Editor Window and it magically pops up...  This happens also on a build of the game (on Android for example, it is drawn when screen orientation changes but not before...).

I tried to Force canvas redraw, LayoutForceRebuild but it doesn't work. The fact is that i have no idea why this is happening...

Screen shot 1 : 
[image]

Screen shot 2 : the red arrow shows what I did to make it drawn
[image]

Screen shot 3 : with Show mask enabled on the view port
[image]

Screen shot 4 : same as 3 but after resize
[image]

Comment: You do need to show the code where you dynamically items to the scroll-view.

Comment: there is no special code to show when this is also happening when I drag and drop the ListElement from the Project folder to the hierarchy. The code is basically a call to Instantiate the prefab with the Content's transform as parent...

Comment: On the scrollview object (or its viewport, I forget which) there will be a mask. Can you enable "show mask" and screenshot it in both scenarios?

Comment: @Draco18s the viewport indeed has it. It checked the "show mask". You can see that the second list Element doesn't show up until I resize the game view.

Comment: Any layout fitter script are you using on content gameobject? If so one suggestion is try to remove and see if it is working. Second solution is create another scroll view and try adding elements with default settings ie without adding any additional scripts and compare with your current scroll view. That should give you idea what might be happening

Comment: Yeah, I'm at a loss. Delete everything and start over as killer_mech says.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to fix this without strating again from scratch but it seems like I have no choice indeed

Comment: @PierreBaret have you fixed it by remaking the thing? I currently have the exact same issue = only editor window resize fixes it.

Comment: @Paprik yes I ended up rebuilding it from scratch and from what I can remember the problem disappeared. Is it still happening with the latest versions of Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I met with this problem too and finally solved it, dunno whether  it's a same situation.

I find the window or UI Elements repaints only when refered variables are changed. So when it comes to the ListView, it is not called "OnValueChanged" if you add elements to [ListView.itemsSource]. The solution is to new a list and assign to [ListView.itemsSource].